# firestore trigger functions not uploading to the firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, triggers

I am currently working on a web application to where a customer can come and request a private event for a valet company. I am trying to set up a trigger function so it can send an email to the owner evertytime someone requests a private event. I currently ahve this code set up in my email.js file

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions');
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 admin.initializeApp();

 const db = admin.firestore();

exports.onQuoteAdded = functions.firestore.document('Manager/Quote/Quotes').onCreate( (snap, context) =>{
const values = snap.data();

//send email

db.collection('login').add({ description: 'Email was sent'});

});
```

I try to do the firebase deploy --only functions. I do that it says deployed succesfully. I then go into my firestore i add a new file under Quotes and nothing happens. I then also check the functions page within firebase and it says waiting on your first deploy. Does anyone know what i could to to figure out where the errror is.

Comment: "I add a new file under Quotes" What do you exactly mean??

Comment: @RenaudTarnec i add a new private event request from the website.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec so i went ahead and changed the path that you said was wrong and it still does not create a function for me within the firebase website under functions

Comment: @RenaudTarnec i went ahead and created a JS and a TS file. I copied the code they had in the video into my TS file and it still does not upload a fucntion to the web. I also did the same code in a JS file and still does not upload the functions

Comment: Can you try this official tutorial: https://youtu.be/DYfP-UIKxH0

Comment: @RenaudTarnec that is the tutorial i tried. And it still did not upload. I tried something else and i think i just messed up my code and i have no clue how to fix it. I re did the firebase init and now it is giving me a huge error Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
npm ERR! missing script: lint

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-26T18_12_28_488Z-debug.log

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Okay i fixed that problem but now i am getting this problem could not deploy functions because the "functions" directory was not found. Please create it or specify a different source directory in firebase.json

Comment: @RenaudTarnec okay i am back where i started

Comment: Yes the best is to start from a clean project and try to deploy the Cloud Function from the example. Then you modify it to cover your case.

Comment: so i would have to re create the whole website? the domain again and everything within firebase

Comment: Just start with a test clean project. Just to be sure you can deploy a simple function and make sure you don’t miss something

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud Function  defined with `functions.firestore.document('Manager/Quote/Quotes').onCreate()` cannot deploy correctly because you are passing a wrong path to the [`document()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore#document) method.

You need to pass a path that points to a Document, i.e. the path must contain an even number of slash-separated path elements, like:

`functions.firestore.document('Manager/Quote').onCreate()`

or

`functions.firestore.document('Manager/{quoteId}').onCreate()`

or, for a subcollection,

`functions.firestore.document('Manager/{ManagerId}/subColl/{docId}').onCreate()`

---

You most probably want to use a wildcard, as shown in the second option above and as detailed in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters).

---

I would also suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the [Firebase video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) which emphasize how it is important to correctly manage the Cloud Function life cycle, by returning a Promise when all the asynchronous work is complete.

Comment: Hello @AlexButean, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?